# MYSQL Setting Chronological Order

Tags: mysql

```
select guest_frs, guest_sur, town, customer.postcode 
from table1,table2 
where name = "xxxxx"
```

I need to put names of clients in chronological order on mysql but I'm unsure on how to do this. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

```
select guest_frs, guest_sur, town, customer.postcode, yourfield
from table1,table2 
where name = "xxxxx"
order by yourfield ASC
```

Comment: I added

    select guest_frs, guest_sur, town, customer.postcode 
    from table1,table2 
    where name = "xxxxx"
    Order by dataofarrival ASC

But I'm getting an error. It says unknown column in order clause (column exists).

Comment: @LibyasFinest. You wrote data instead of date. See if it isn't a typo

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on here. Basically, it's saying the date doesn't exist. Do I have to include at it the top maybe?

Comment: Try to add it in select `SELECT guest_frs, guest_sur, town, customer.postcode, dataofarrival`

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what I'm missing. Cheers FBHY. I completely forgot to add it at the top.